# Copy data and structure from one live database to a test db without losing data

Tags: export, mysql, workbench

I need to get a copy of a live database to create a test environment database using MySQL Workbench.  If I use the Data Export tool to export to a Self-Contained File (filename.sql) - will I lose any information on the live server or is it just backing up the data?  The word 'Dump' really concerns me...as if I'm "cutting and pasting" instead of "copy and paste".  It's absolutely vital that I keep all the data on the live server.  Hopefully my question made sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line "mysqldump" might be quicker

```
mysqldump -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db1 | mysql -h [server] -u [user] -p[password] db2
```

However MySQL Workbench will do pretty much the same thing, mysqldump doesnt delete your information.